# Deplaning in Mexico City before final destination

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, mexico

I have a single Air France ticket, flying from Bangalore to Mazatlan, with connections in Paris and Mexico City. All flights are operated by Air France.

Now my plan has changed and I have to go to Culiacan, not Mazatlan. I want to deplane in Mexico City and retrieve my checked luggage. How can I do this?

Comment: You rebook your flight only to Mexico City. Or don't check bags.

Comment: Note that if this is the first half a round trip ticket, the airline will cancel your entire reservation if you do not fly every flight on your itinerary in order. In other words, if you do not board the plane in Mexico City, the rest of your tickets will be completely cancelled. The only way to avoid this is to contact the airline and find out how much it will cost to rebook your ticket.

Comment: @Roddy The OP will almost certainly clear Mexican customs at Mexico City, so they can collect their bags.  As Zach points out, the primary risk is that their return flight gets cancelled.

Comment: @Roddy MEX-MZT is a domestic flight, it's a codeshare on AM. So customs will be done at MEX. However the ticket still ought to be changed because we cannot rely on AM failing to notify AF of the missed segment.

Answer (score 1):

You should contact Air France (or your travel agent, if you booked indirectly) and ask for the ticket to be changed.

I looked at the Air France fare tariff and the price of Bangalore-Culiacan is calculated in exactly the same way as Bangalore-Mazatalan. So I would not expect the price to change, although if your flight is in the near future I may be wrong because flights will begin to fill up.

Depending which fare you purchased, there will be change fee, which again from skim-reading Air France's tariff guide, I would expect to be 5000 INR or less.

Your alternative is to collect your bags at Mexican customs in Mexico City and then abandon your onward flight. I would not recommend this because the remainder of your ticket (including the return flights) may be voided.